# how to put the value of text field using onkeydown and automatically write a paragraph

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I created an input field

and now i want that anything user put in text field above that should automatically get written below in a paragraph. i want it be done by onkeydown event of javascript.

Comment: Please add some code to show us your efforts

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/wmwy6vnL/)

Here is the simple markup

```
<input id="text1">

<p id="para1"></p>
```

and JS code to bind events and test

```
document.getElementById( "text1" ).addEventListener( "keydown", function(){

   document.getElementById( "para1" ).innerHTML = this.value;

}, false );
```